# Readings of 120V coming to the electrical outlet but not powering anything

Tags: electrical

I have readings of 120V coming to the electrical outlet but not powering anything, I have several outlets with this issue. The breaker box is good and breakers are good. Several outlets and a closet light are not working and the outlets that aren’t working are in several rooms. I now used a voltage meter and it shows 120 volts.

Comment: Can you turn the breaker off and use your meter on continuity mode to see if there's a reading between neutral and ground at the outlets that don't work?

Comment: Sorry at the moment no . I recently moved in but the problem occurred recently and I’m a chef and claim to no not much about electrical, I can say that when the issue started the closet light was giving out half the power and now not at all.

Comment: Most digital voltage meters are *high impedance*, and are measuring the tiny electrostatic current coupled to the wire. Use a small test lamp, e.g. a neon voltage tester (which is still fairly high impedance).

Comment: Current flows in loops.  It's not enough for the hot wire to ding as "hot", current must also be able to return.  "breakers are good" check your neutrals.

Comment: it's probably phantom voltage,  try the light switch, see if that helps.